# Navigation list improvement needed

Tags: javascript, html

I made a simple html navigation list + some javascript. The thing is that i want a value to be returned when i select an option and click submit , but the value just vanishes in like 1 sec , here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<title>lol</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" name="form">
       <input type="text" id="hp">

       <select name="" id="lol">
            <option value="neki1">neki1</option>
            <option value="neki2">neki2</option>
            <option value="neki3">neki3</option>
       </select>

       <input type="submit" onmousedown="radi()">   
       </form>
       <script type="text/javascript">
         function radi () {
            var x = document.getElementById('lol').selectedIndex,
            y = document.getElementById('lol').options,
            z = Number(document.form.hp.value),
            zSum = 0;

            if(y[x].text === "neki1"){
            zSum = z + 20;
            }

            else if(y[x].text === "neki2" ){
            zSum = z + 35;
            }

            else if(y[x].text === "neki3" ){
            zSum = z + 55;
            }

            document.form.hp.value = zSum;
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:Also i want the old value to subtract if i change the option :)) , and yes the first question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for 2nd Question

user `parseInt()` method of javascript to convert value from textbox back to integer. 
and if the value is non 0 then do the substraction as needed.

```
parseInt(document.form.hp.value)
```

Comment: don't get it ... parseint() = number()

Comment: you want to delete old value from `document.form.hp.value`  right? so suppose user selects neki1 first `document.form.hp.value` changed to 20. then user changes it to neki2 you want 20 to be substracted right? Or I am understanding question wrong?

Comment: in your case z alady has that value 2nd time the code is executed right? so instead of `zSum=z+20` use `zsum=20` that should solve your problem . you need not subtract it at all.

Comment: thanks :) it helped in this case and it could probably in the real thing :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not stopping the form from submitting and the page is reloading. Change the button code to:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return radi()">
```

and at the end of your function add

```
return false;
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/A59SV/1/)**

Comment: Thanks , but how can i subtract the old value if i select an other option?

Comment: That would require binding to the onchange event of the select menu and subtracting the value based on the option.

Comment: so yet another function must be made?